# Django query orderby

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a queryset in Django. My queries continue in the following order. But it doesn't implement the order_by operation. What is the problem?
The first two queries are working

```
all_products = Product.objects.filter(category=category.id)
all_products = all_products.filter(price__gte=100)
all_products = all_products.order_by('price')
```

product models:

```
header = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=False, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 verbose_name="Category")

price = models.FloatField(null=True, verbose_name="Product Price")
```

Comment: What is `price`? Can you share the relevant parts of your `Product` model?

Comment: I added product models.

Comment: exactly what is the problem? Why do you assume `.order_by('price')` does not work?

Comment: Because Django not sorted by price. This sorted by standart rules. I tested .order_by('-price') but didn't work either

Comment: and how do you *render* the queryset?

Comment: Sorry. I'm missing something. Büyüksün kral.